# PHP - date_diff with more of three elements

Tags: php

I'm trying with the function date_diff of php language. I need to do operations with three or more values.

For example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('11:00:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('10:00:00');

$totalDate = date_diff($date1, $date2);
echo "<br>TOTAL: ".$totalDate->format('%H:%i:%s');

$date3 = new DateTime('02:00:00');
$totalDate2 = date_diff($totalDate, $date3);
echo "<br>TOTAL: ".$totalDate2->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

In the code it can see there are two values(date1 and date2) to substract and the result to substract with another value(date3). The problem is here. the first operation is working fine but the second operation use the result of the first operation($totalDate) and when I want to run the second operation doesn't work.

The logfile of the server is this:

*[Tue Nov 08 17:47:03.309115 2016] [:error] [pid 78386] [client 192.168.0.4:54695] PHP Warning:  date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, object given
[Tue Nov 08 17:47:03.309165 2016] [:error] [pid 78386] [client 192.168.0.4:54695] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on boolean*

I'm sure that the problem is with the variable $totalDate is not a DateTime class. I have tried with this: `$totalDate = new DateTime(date_diff($date1, $date2)` but it doesn't work again :(

Please Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What you need is `date_diff($date1, $date3);` or `date_diff($date2, $date3);`

Comment: I need: `$result1 = date_diff($date1, $date2)` and `$result2 = date_diff($result1, $date3)` The problem is using result1 to the second date_diff

Comment: Are you sure??? `$result1` is a difference (`DateInterval`) and not a DateTime object. I think you are trying to compare Apples and Oranges

Comment: @ruzD how do you imaging this? The first diff will be a number, like 14. Now, you want to know the difference between the number 14 and Tuesday?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know it but are there another option for this?

Comment: @Dainis Abols the $result1 is example: 01:00:00 and I want to substract to $date3 example: 00:30:00

Comment: You need to find the diff, that will be `1 hour` and then subtract that from another time? Like 15:00 - 1h ? Try this - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two concepts: DateTime and DateInterval.

You're mismatching two different ideas.

```
$dateTime1 = new DateTime('11:00:00'); // DateTime() returns DateTime object.
$dateTime2 = new DateTime('10:00:00'); // DateTime() returns DateTime object.

$dateInterval1 = date_diff($dateTime1, $dateTime2); // date_diff() returns DateInterval object. http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
echo "<br>Difference1: " . $dateInterval1->format('%H:%i:%s'); // (11 - 10) = 1

$dateTime3 = new DateTime('02:00:00');
$dateString = $dateInterval1->format('%H:%i:%s');
$dateTime4 = new DateTime($dateString);
$dateInterval2 = date_diff($dateTime4, $dateTime3);
echo "<br>Difference2: " . $dateInterval2->format('%H:%i:%s'); // (1 - 2) = |-1| = 1

// Output
// Difference1: 01:0:0
// Difference2: 01:0:0
```